# Attaching an Object Residing on Domino Server to Email (Lotusscript preferred)

Tags: email, lotus-domino, attachment

*Not sure if this question is more appropriate for ServerFault or StackOverflow, sorry if it should belong elsewhere!*

I am working on an application and one of the function is to automatically send an email with an attachment. I can code the application to attach the object when it resides on local or on a mapped drive.

Newbie Question: Is there a way to have the object reside on the Domino server, and still be able to point to it and have the application automatically attach and send? Is there any method that allows me to do this?

Users have no direct access to the server/filesystem, so mapped drive of the Domino server is out of the question.

Hope someone can shed some light on this question. Thanks!

**Edit:**
To make it clearer, I will include some code.

`'Attach reports here`
`Set EmbObj = Rtitem.EmbedObject(EMBED_ATTACHMENT,"", "T:\IS\Foo\Report_1.doc")`
`Set EmbObj = Rtitem.EmbedObject(EMBED_ATTACHMENT,"", "T:\IS\Foo\Graph.pdf")`

The code above attaches 2 objects to the email and later sends it out. It works because I have a mapped drive (fileserver mapped to T:). But if I want to have the 2 objects on the Domino server (and no mapped drive allowed), it would fail.

So far I tried `Set EmbObj = Rtitem.EmbedObject(EMBED_ATTACHMENT,"", "\Report\Graph.pdf")` which does not work (I guess it is still interpreting the path of the obj based on the user's environment).

How do I make it so that it finds the object on the server instead? Are there other methods I should be using?

Comment: Flagged it to move it to stackoverflow. If the file resides inside a database on the domino server, you can just link to it in the mail.
Or you can put the files in the http folder of the domino server and offer them via http download.

Answer (score 0):

When your application (I presume you are writing it in LotusScript as agent?) runs on the server, then the server's file system is visible as local file system. So attaching the document would work. If you run the agent locally on a Notes client you can use an agent.runOnServer call to run part of your code on the server. agent.runOnServer can also be called from COM (in case you don't use LotusScript or Java).